# Is this system of differential equations coupled or not?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$\begin{aligned} \dot{x_{1}} &= a\\ \dot{x_{2}} &= b \sin\Bigl(\omega(t-x_{1})\Bigr) \end{aligned}$$

Does it follow from here that $ x_{1} = at+c $? Or do I have to turn it into a single higher-order differential equation and then solve it? How to spot the difference easily?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right to think you can solve for $x_1$, then use this to solve for $x_2$. Whether we say they're "coupled" is more of a semantic question, but I'd say yes.